# Lubuntu make a contribution of funds?

Tags: lubuntu, contributing

How do you contribute Funds to the Lubuntu project? I only want to make a small contribution to it. And I have is installed on a old computer.

Comment: I added an update to this as the Lubuntu Foundation is now the funding backing for Lubuntu - Canonical no longer provides direct financial support to the project.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like we can't do it directly.

Answer from Lubuntu Dev (who doesn't have enough time for Lubuntu anymore):
https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/lubuntu-users/2012-March/000826.html

But you can support **LXDE**: https://salt.bountysource.com/teams/lxle

Answer (score 0):

Canonical the company that publishes Lubuntu isn't going out of business anytime soon. Much like Microsoft gives discounts to schools and students, Canonical makes software free for home users and small businesses who do a lot of the testing and feature requests. Then it charges support contracts to larger corporations to keep the lights on and staff paid.

Besides direct funding you could consider [buying Canonical / Ubuntu T-shirts](https://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=14) and hats. This will not only provide funds but "spread the word" to other Windows and Mac users:

[image: canonical t-shirts and hats.png]

Comment: This is no longer valid - Canonical does not provide direct funding anymore to the Lubuntu Project.  See my answer with details to donate to the Lubuntu Foundation which is the primary backing for the Lubuntu Project.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2020, the Lubuntu project is funded by community donations to the Lubuntu Foundation.

These donation receipts (by source) and disbursements of payments are documented publicly.

Details on the various mechanisms for donating are listed on the [Lubuntu Official Site's Donations Page](https://lubuntu.me/donate/).